# Add page number on moderncv of classic style

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, moderncv

I am aware that this question has been posted a couple of times but none of the answers seem to work with the most up-to-date version of moderncv.

https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv

This is where you can download it. I am also using template.tex as my minimal working example. The only changes I've made are:

1. `\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, roman]{moderncv}` - Changed paper size and font.
2. `\moderncvstyle{classic}` - I am using the classic theme instead of the default one.

I am trying to have the center footer of each page say "Page X of Y". In previous version I was able to do so by:

1. Making sure that `%\nopagenumbers{}` stays commented and
2. Adding `\cfoot{\addressfont\itshape\textcolor{gray}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}` in the preamble. That, of course, required the `lastpage` package.

However, this does not work for this version. Please note that I am using the **classic** theme.

I suspect that something has to be added/changed in moderncvstyleclassic.sty or moderncv.cls but I am not sure what to do. Any help would be much appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your code as

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}                   
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%************************************************ added <<<<
\usepackage{lastpage}
\cfoot{\addressfont\itshape\textcolor{gray}{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
\setlength{\footskip}{50pt} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< adjust
%*********************************************************
```

[image: b]

The template sets the `\footskip` to 136pt pushing the footer off the page.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the problem. I did not notice the \footskip line in the template.